# Enable SSL3 in Windows Server 2016

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2016

We have an app that requires SSL3 to be enabled on Windows Server 2016. The server is internal, no public access.

I followed the steps from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings#ssl-30

Except I set enabled to 1. But the server still does not accept SSL3 connections.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is a terrible idea, but if you absolutely have to make something work with SSL v3 on server '16, then you then are going to need to modify other SChannel settings to enable legacy Ciphers/Cipher Suites/Hashes/Key Exchanges as well as enabling the sslv3 protocol itself.

All SChannel settings are configured in the keys under: `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\`. Theres plenty of guides to securing SSLv3 on Server 2003 & 2008 - pretty sure the registry paths are unchanged - but im not sure if server 2016 will actually support the required combination of the above (im guessing its all still there and disabled). Based on the age if your system you should be able to work out likely supported configs. Also, seem to think there is a value called `DisableByDefault` as well as `Enabled` on some of the schannel subkeys.

*DISCLAIMER* - this is a terrible idea - SChannel is used by many Windows services and your proposed configuration opens up the entire server to unnecessary risks (e.g Powershell remoting and RDP also rely on SChannel).

Few things you should consider...

- By weakening the server side, will you also have to make client side changes to allow other systems (or worse actual desktops & laptops) to make a connection?
- Just because something is on your internal network, dont assume it cant be attacked (via hacked WIFI, or malware etc). Make sure its in a DMZ/VLAN/firewalled (inbound and outbound) so you can tightly control access and reduce the risks.
- I'm assuming whatever it is that requires SSLV3 is unmaintainable, might it be possible use a Proxy of some description to either offload SSL entirley, or act as a "man-in-the-middle" and decrypt/re-encrypt traffic from SSLv3 to TLS.